# Can a convex function have local maxima?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have read that a convex function can have local maxima. 
It seems that this must happen on the boundary of the domain, otherwise there should be a region in which the function is concave.

Is this true?

Comment: Counterexample $y(x)=0$. Should be strictly convex.

Comment: y = x is also true but it is not strictly convex.

Comment: @M.T OK, then there must be no intervals, where function $=0$.

Comment: OK, I understand that if all the local maxima are on an  interval in which the function is constant then there can be local maxima not on the boundary. Is this the only case?

Comment: Every global maximum is a particular local maximum.

Comment: I think the easiest way to focus your question is to limit yourself to convex functions that are not also concave. In that case, the maximum must be along the boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ attains its maximum, $M$, at some point $a$. Since $f$ is convex, the set $\{x:f(x)<M\}$ is convex. This set does not contain $a$; therefore it lies in a closed halfplane with $a$ on its boundary. After some further considerations involving convexity of $f$, it follows that either $f\equiv M$, or $a$ is a boundary point of the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

For a convex function that is not constant on any open set, a local maximum can only occur at the boundary of the domain. For example, the distance between two vectors $$\Vert x-y \Vert_2 $$ is not strictly convex. However, since it is not constant it does not have a local maxima on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n $.